# Why am I unable to use mockResolvedValue here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, react-testing-library

I’m unclear on how to mock my api response when using the following setup.

I have the following test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, render, wait } from '@testing-library/react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Condition from './index.jsx';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    create: jest.fn(() => ({
      get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: {} }),
      interceptors: {
        request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
        response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
      },
    })),
  };
});


afterEach(cleanup);

test('fetches and displays data', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'mock data' });
  const { container } = render(<Condition {...props} />);
  await wait(() => expect(container.textContent).toContain('Current milestone'));
  expect(container).toBeDefined();
});
```

… and the following api helper:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: window.apiPath,
  withCredentials: true,
});

api.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const newConfig = Object.assign({}, config);
  newConfig.headers.Accept = 'application/json';

  return newConfig;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));

export default api;
```

My `Condition` component uses the following function to fetch data when it mounts:

```js
const fetchAsync = async endpoint => {
  const result = await api.get(endpoint);
  setSuffixOptions(result.data.data);
  console.log('result.data.data', result.data.data);
};
```

The `axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'mock data' });` line in the test causes the following error:

```sh
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockResolvedValue' of undefined

      124 |
      125 | test('fetches and displays data', async () => {
    > 126 |   axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'mock data' });
          |             ^
      127 |   const { container } = render(<Condition {...props} />);
      128 |   await wait(() => expect(container.textContent).toContain('Current milestone'));
      129 |   expect(container).toBeDefined();
```

Should I be using a different method for mocking the response?

**EDIT**
Calling `axios.create.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'mock data' });` results in the same error.

Comment: Because your Axios test double only has a create prop, no get.

Comment: But the create method is what creates the api which has the get and interceptors methods in the api file. How do I modify `axios.get.mockResolvedValue` for that shape?

Comment: Sure, but you're *not calling that in the test*.

Comment: Calling `axios.create.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'mock data' });` results in the same error.

Comment: `axios.create.get` is trying to access the `get` prop *on* the function, it doesn't *call* the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To mock your api response, you can use `jest.spyOn` in combination with `mockImplementation`, e.g. as follows:

```
import api from './api';

const mock = jest.spyOn(api,"get");
mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }));
```

In the example above, the `api.get` method is replaced to emulate a successful call returning `{ data: 'mock data' }`.

It can be placed in your `test` function as follows:

```
test('fetches and displays data', async () => {
    const mock = jest.spyOn(api, "get");
    mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }));
    const { container } = render(<Condition {...props} />);
    await wait(() => expect(container.textContent).toContain('Current milestone'));
    expect(container).toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: Where would I pass the response data in?

Comment: inside Promise.resolve, like this: `mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))`

Comment: Mind dropping that in the answer? Then I’ll accept.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to mock the `./api` helper module rather than `axios` module. Because you are testing the component which imports `./api` as its direct dependency. For the component, the `axios` module is indirect dependency. If you want to test `./api` helper, then you should mock `axios` module, because now, it becomes a direct dependency for `./api`.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import api from './api';

function Condition(props) {
  const [options, setSuffixOptions] = useState();
  const fetchAsync = async (endpoint) => {
    const result = await api.get(endpoint);
    setSuffixOptions(result.data);
    console.log('result.data', result.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAsync('http://localhost:3000/api');
  });

  return <div>{options}</div>;
}

export default Condition;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Condition from './';
import { render, wait } from '@testing-library/react';
import api from './api';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./api', () => {
  return { get: jest.fn() };
});

describe('63981693', () => {
  test('fetches and displays data', async () => {
    mocked(api.get).mockResolvedValue({ data: 'mock data' });
    const props = {};
    const { container } = render(<Condition {...props} />);
    await wait(() => expect(container.textContent).toContain('mock data'));
    expect(api.get).toBeCalledWith('http://localhost:3000/api');
    expect(container).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

We don't care about the implementation of the `./api` module because we have mocked it.

unit test result with coverage report:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63981693/index.test.tsx (12.377s)
  63981693
    ✓ fetches and displays data (68ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/63981693/index.tsx:1461
    result.data mock data

  console.log src/stackoverflow/63981693/index.tsx:1461
    result.data mock data

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.873s, estimated 18s
```

Comment: You use `ts-jest` here but the project is not written in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can mock the same method with multiple conditions:

**Import the Axios:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
```

**Use the mockedAxios:**

```
const mock = jest.spyOn(mockedAxios, 'post');
mock.mockImplementation((url): any => {
  if (url.indexOf('checkAddOnEligibility') > 0) {
    return { data: [{ validationMessage: { value: '' }, isValid: { value: true } }] };
  }
  return {
    data: [
      {
        thirdYearPremium: 48945,
        secondYearPremium: 30535,
        firstYearPremium: 2000,
      },
    ],
  };
});
```